# Spring Boot 1.4 - TestRestTemplate Unsatisfied dependency exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot, autowired

Have a very light Spring Boot 1.4 project, generated from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io).

Trying to run an intergration test for `@RestController` with `@RequestBody` using `TestRestTemplate`, but there's no success because of a startup exception.

The only configuration class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration file `application.properties` has almost nothing except of `security.ignored=/**` for the test purposes.

The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
public class MyControllerTest {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Before
    public void init() {

        log.info("Initializing...");
    }

    @Test
    public void addTest() throws Exception {

        log.info("MyController add test starting...");

        // restTemplate usage

        log.info("MyController add test passed");
    }
}
```

... but during the test startup I get the following exception:

```
ERROR 6504 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener@5444f1c3] to prepare test instance [com.myproject.controllers.MyControllerTest@5d2bc446]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myproject.controllers.MyControllerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

According to the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) it's not required to configure `TestRestTemplate` anywhere. However, I've added the latest Apache Http Client to the classpath as it recommended.

What have I missed?

Comment: Just have found `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` annotation should be used in conjuction with `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@DataJpaTest` in the case like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying `@DataJpaTest` which tells Spring to exclude any wiring of the web context for the tests. As such there is no TestRestTemplate created. Read this blog for more details around testing slices of your application: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#testing-application-slices

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running the main class on Eclipse using **Serenity BDD** tests with a **spring-boot**. It starts to fail after I have added the `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` test dependency. That happens because Eclipse put everything in just one classloader. In order to fix this error, I have created one configuration class overriding the default behavior of the **spring-boot**. This code was based in one spring class (the scope not is public) `SpringBootTestContextCustomizer.TestRestTemplateFactory`

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    // Overriding Default Spring Boot TestRestTemplate to allow 
    // execute the main method from Eclipse (mixed Classloader) 
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate(ApplicationContext context, RestTemplateBuilder templateBuilder) {
        final AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container = context.getBean(AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.class);
        final boolean sslEnabled = container.getSsl() != null && container.getSsl().isEnabled();
        final TestRestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate(templateBuilder.build(), null, null, sslEnabled? new HttpClientOption[]{}: new HttpClientOption[]{HttpClientOption.SSL});
        template.setUriTemplateHandler(new LocalHostUriTemplateHandler(context.getEnvironment(), sslEnabled ? "https" : "http"));
        return template;
    }
}
```